# JSON to Data Table Mapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatable

I have my JSON Data in the below format

```
{
  "RegX": {
    "LayerA": {
      "name": "abcd123",
      "url": "htt:cd1234"
    },
    "LayerB": {
      "name": "xyz234",
      "url": "ht:bcd12"
    }
  },
  "RegY": {
    "Layer1": {
      "name": "xyz123",
      "url": "ht/abc1234"
    },
    "Layer2": {
      "name": "xy234",
      "url": "http://abc12"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to display this in a datatable in below format .

### TABLE NAME - REGX

```
     NAME                URL
LAYERA  abcd123        httd1234
LAYERB  xyz234         http:cd12
```

### TABLE NAME - REGY

```
    NAME                URL
LAYER1  xyz123        http:d1234
LAYER2  xyz234         h/abcd12
```

Is there a way that i can display single JSON file in two different tables and display proper Row names and Column names also from JSON table ? I am planning to use datatables but not able to find proper implementation to use

Comment: yes! what is the issue?

Comment: This question asks people to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource - this is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: My question is how to i use datatable to create two diffent tables from same JSON ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myData = {
  "RegX": {
    "LayerA": {
      "name": "abcd123",
      "url": "htt:cd1234"
    },
    "LayerB": {
      "name": "xyz234",
      "url": "ht:bcd12"
    }
  },
  "RegY": {
    "Layer1": {
      "name": "xyz123",
      "url": "ht/abc1234"
    },
    "Layer2": {
      "name": "xy234",
      "url": "http://abc12"
    }
  }
};

var tables = Object.keys(myData);

for(var i=0; i<tables.length; i++){
  var rows = Object.keys(myData[tables[i]]);
  var tbl = document.createElement('table');
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(tbl);
  var thead = tbl.appendChild(document.createElement('thead'));
  thead.innerHTML = ("<tr><td>name</td><td>url</td></tr>");
  var tbdy = document.createElement('tbody');
  tbl.appendChild(tbdy);
  for(var j=0; j<rows.length; j++){
    var cols = Object.keys(myData[tables[i]][rows[j]]);
    var innerHTML = '';
    var tr = tbdy.insertRow(j);
    for(var k=0; k<cols.length; k++){
      innerHTML += "<td>"+myData[tables[i]][rows[j]][cols[k]]+"</td>";
    }
    tr.innerHTML = innerHTML;
  }
  
}
```

```css
table, tr , td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

table {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

Try to understand the code and add more to fulfill your needs.
Hope you got it, if not ask me.

Comment: Thank you Sai ..I am looking to implement using datatable but this is really helpfull